# Inserting list into list containing multiple list

Tags: python, list, addition

for knowledge purpose

```
Input:

    [[[[[], [], []]], ['trynda'], [[[], [], []]]], ['cait'], [[[[], [], []]], ['veigar'], [[[], [], []]]]]

Output:

    [[[[[], [x], []]], ['trynda'], [[[], [], []]]], ['cait'], [[[[], [], []]], ['veigar'], [[[], [], []]]]]
```

How do I add x into the 2nd list of the list of the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use nested indices (as appropriate for a *nested list*):

```
original_list[0][0][0][1].append(x)  # 2nd of 1st of 1st of 1st.
```

That assumes `x` is a variable. Otherwise, use a string i.e. `'x'`.

Demo:

```
>>> original_list = [[[[[], [], []]], ['trynda'], [[[], [], []]]], ['cait'], [[[[], [], []]], ['veigar'], [[[], [], []]]]]
>>> original_list[0][0][0][1].append('x')
>>> original_list
[[[[[], ['x'], []]], ['trynda'], [[[], [], []]]], ['cait'], [[[[], [], []]], ['veigar'], [[[], [], []]]]]
          ^
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list[0][0][0][1].append(x)
```

Assuming that `x` contains a value.  You'd want `'x'` if it were a string.

Comment: Never use 'list' as variable name, because it is python reserved name.

Comment: @thefourtheye It is not a builtin function, it is type, if you want to be fully precise =)

Comment: It is both a type and a built-in function.  In the context of my bad choice of variable name, I would've been overwriting the built-in function https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list